what is the best way to ignore eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
I have a useEffect hook look like this:
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // navigate from pdf to source
    if (srcFocus && srcFocus.length > 0) {
      let pos: SrcPosition = srcFocus[0];
      let name_paths = pos.file.split("/");
      ProjectTreeFolder.handleExpandFolder(
        name_paths,
        props,
        selectedFile
      );
    }
  }, [srcFocus, props]);

now I only want to trigger this effect when srcFocus change, but the eslint always told me add selectedFile to dependencies array.
what is the best practice if I really need triiger useEffect only when srcFocus change? I am sure did not need to trigger the useEffect when props or selectedFile change. also did not want do disable the eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps check.

I am afraid there is not much you can do when you do not want to follow any of the above option. Maybe show more of your code, so one can see if any refactoring might help but I think there is close to zero chance of that.

There was RFC to introduce new hook useEvent exactly for that. That RFC was closed and another should be raised, but I don't see what is the replacement.
You could try user-land implementations for useEvent idea, e.g. react-use-event-hook
import useEvent from 'react-use-event-hook';

const onExpandFolder = (name_paths) => 
      ProjectTreeFolder.handleExpandFolder(
        name_paths,
        props,
        selectedFile
      );

useEffect(() => {
    // navigate from pdf to source
    if (srcFocus && srcFocus.length > 0) {
      let pos: SrcPosition = srcFocus[0];
      let name_paths = pos.file.split("/");
      onExpandFolder(name_paths);
    }
  }, [srcFocus]);


However, if you call onExpandFolder in async way, its closure may refer to old data:
  setTimeout(() => {
    // before next executes, we may have `selectedFile` be changed
    onExpandFolder(some_name_paths)
  }, 1000)

Then, probably, the only way is to use useRef directly:
const onExpandFolderRef = useRef()
onExpandFolderRef.current = (name_path) => 
      ProjectTreeFolder.handleExpandFolder(
        name_paths,
        props,
        selectedFile
      );

.....

setTimeout(() => {
  // even if `selectedFile` is changed, we will run the most recent version with fresh references in the closure
  onExpandFolderRef.current(some_name_paths)
}, 1000)

